# Sharepoint REST ValidateUpdateListItem return error response

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api

any help would be appreciated
Thank you

SharePoint 2019 on-premise

I'm making a REST request using ValidateUpdateListItem to update Author and Editor; however, I'm getting an error message: Multiple entries matched; please click to resolve. In the response, the user with that email only has one record.

**Note:** Window's Authentication and Claims Web application configure for a single site collection.

**Request:**

```
_api/web/GetList(@path)/items(5)/ValidateUpdateListItem()?@path=%27/sites/Some Documents%27

Formatted data
{
   "formValues":[
      {
         "__metadata":{
            "type":"SP.ListItemFormUpdateValue"
         },
         "FieldName":"Created_x0020_By",
         "FieldValue":"i:0e.t|original-issuer|joe.average@noemail.com"
      },
      {
         "__metadata":{
            "type":"SP.ListItemFormUpdateValue"
         },
         "FieldName":"Author",
         "FieldValue":"[{'Key':'joe.average@noemail.com'}]"
      },
      {
         "__metadata":{
            "type":"SP.ListItemFormUpdateValue"
         },
         "FieldName":"Created",
         "FieldValue":"09/15/2022 04:27 PM"
      },
      {
         "__metadata":{
            "type":"SP.ListItemFormUpdateValue"
         },
         "FieldName":"Modified_x0020_By",
         "FieldValue":"i:0e.t|original-issuer|joe.average@noemail.com"
      },
      {
         "__metadata":{
            "type":"SP.ListItemFormUpdateValue"
         },
         "FieldName":"Editor",
         "FieldValue":"[{'Key':'joe.average@noemail.com'}]"
      },
      {
         "__metadata":{
            "type":"SP.ListItemFormUpdateValue"
         },
         "FieldName":"Modified",
         "FieldValue":"09/15/2022 04:27 PM"
      }
   ],
   "bNewDocumentUpdate":true
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
   "d":{
      "ValidateUpdateListItem":{
         "__metadata":{
            "type":"Collection(SP.ListItemFormUpdateValue)"
         },
         "results":[
            {
               "ErrorMessage":null,
               "FieldName":"Created_x0020_By",
               "FieldValue":"i:0e.t|original-issuer|joe.average@noemail.com",
               "HasException":false
            },
            {
               "ErrorMessage":"Multiple entries matched, please click to resolve.",
               "FieldName":"Author",
               "FieldValue":"[{'Key':'joe.average@noemail.com'}]",
               "HasException":true
            },
            {
               "ErrorMessage":null,
               "FieldName":"Created",
               "FieldValue":"09/15/2022 04:27 PM",
               "HasException":false
            },
            {
               "ErrorMessage":null,
               "FieldName":"Modified_x0020_By",
               "FieldValue":"i:0e.t|original-issuer|joe.average@noemail.com",
               "HasException":false
            },
            {
               "ErrorMessage":"Multiple entries matched, please click to resolve.",
               "FieldName":"Editor",
               "FieldValue":"[{'Key':'joe.average@noemail.com'}]",
               "HasException":true
            },
            {
               "ErrorMessage":null,
               "FieldName":"Modified",
               "FieldValue":"09/15/2022 04:27 PM",
               "HasException":false
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to use LoginName instead of email for Author and Editor field. Try using in this format `"FieldValue":"[{'Key':'i:0e.t|original-issuer|joe.average@noemail.com'}]"` OR `"FieldValue":"[{'Key':'i:0#.f|membership|eve@contoso.com'}]"` for Author and Editor fields. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The field value should be in this form:

`"FieldValue": "[{'Key':'i:0#.w|aaron@testdomain.com'}]"`

Please see [Update file metadata with Rest API using ValidateUpdateListItem in SharePoint on-premises](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/update-file-metadata-with-rest-api-using-validateupdatelistitem/ba-p/1365682) for more information.

Comment: Switching to windows claims won't work for me :(